# Build portable SignalR component with Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin

I have a Windows Phone 8 app that makes use of real time server push via SignalR.

I started to create a Native Android and iOS version of my app, but got stuck at implementing my SignalR component in native Android Java and iOS obj-C.

I have conceptually thought of a way to achieve this by making ONLY JUST the SignalR component portable via Xamarin.

Is it possible to create a Hybrid app in this way ?

And are there any resources online where people have done such.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xamarin would be kind of an all in sort of thing. So all of your Objective-C and JAVA would need to be ported to Xamarin's framework. That might not be a bad idea though ;).

Alternatively, if you are looking for a more cross platform way to implement a SignalR client, you maybe could wrap the logic up in a UIWebView (iOS) or WebView (Android) and use the JavaScript components. Here is an example from Microsoft on [implementing a SignalR client via JavaScript](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client). I don't know how integrated the SignalR functionality is in your app, but this may be an easy way to use it for simple display purposes.

Comment: Yeah, I thought as much..
I'll investigate the UIWebView option, thanks.